# Can't read and write from hard drive

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, root

I have a 1TB hard drive that I recently got, but the problem is that even when formatted I am unable to read and write from the hard drive. Any suggestions? I've tried reformatting it, but the results were the same. The only thing I can think of is that the drive is only accessible by the root user, which is not very convenient.

Comment: Can you mount the hdd?

Comment: Yes, it is mounted.

Comment: ok could you list the permissions on the hdd.. as root `ls -lia`

Comment: I believe the permissions are all just under root.

Comment: ok just plz give the result of the command above

Comment: Did you do any changes or mounted manually/formatted using `root` o.. Usually the drive has to have read/write/execute access via user. Can you also post the output of `ls -l /media/`

Comment: It spit out a bunch of stuff, what are you looking for in particular?

Comment: Im pretty sure GParted has to be root to run, so that makes sense. Here is the drive `root      root      4096 Feb 12 23:08 Storage 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was going into nautilus as root.

```
sudo nautilus
```

Then, at this point, I was classified as the owner of the hard drive and able to change the permissions to the user.